# SUDO_USER undefined in sudo manual - clarification would be lovely

Tags: sudo, root

The following statement appears early in the sudoers manual, it refers to the "SUDO_USER environment variable" but the manual does not define it:

> If sudo is run by root and the SUDO_USER environment variable is set, the sudoers policy will use this value to determine who the actual user is. This can be used by a user to log commands through sudo even when a root shell has been invoked. It also allows the -e option to remain useful even when invoked via a sudo-run script or program. Note, however, that the sudoers lookup is still done for root, not the user specified by SUDO_USER.

This entire paragraph remains fairly elusive to me, any clarification would be appreciated.  For instance, what does it mean that the sudoers policy uses the SUDO_USER environment variable to determine who the user actually is, and what does it mean that it can be used by a user to log commands?

This sentence also eludes me:

> This can be used by a user to log commands through sudo even when a root shell has been invoked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`SUDO_USER` is documented in [`man sudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) (not `sudoers`):

> ```
> SUDO_USER        Set to the login name of the user who invoked sudo.
> ```

That is, if you run `sudo sh -c 'echo $SUDO_USER'` it is a roundabout way of getting the effect of `whoami`.

`sudo` logs when a user runs (or tries to run) a command through it. You can list them with `journalctl /usr/bin/sudo` or something equivalent for your system. It lists the user name and command of each invocation.

If `sudo` is run 1) as root and 2) with `SUDO_USER` set, the log entry will be tagged with the `SUDO_USER` username, rather than as "root". This lets a (cooperating) user record the commands they ran for posterity, even though they were in an unrestricted environment. `sudo` always succeeds when run with root privileges (unless disabled with the `root_sudo` setting), since you could just run the command without it.

There are two main ways this would come up. The first is the obvious `sudo bash` or equivalent and a desire to record things. The other use case is for scripts, which can log the actual actions they took on behalf of users. It's an informative behaviour, not a security issue.

`sudo -e` is used for editing files and uses a different set of security policies, also documented in `man sudo` and somewhat safer editing behaviours. People sometimes use it when logged in as root for those features, and it has the same interaction with `SUDO_USER` as above.

Comment: Thank you Michael for the informative answer, I'll definitely be checking out man sudo.  Thanks again - JC